# Problem with Euler 27

Tags: c++

> ```
> Euler published the remarkable quadratic formula:
>
> n² + n + 41
>
> It turns out that the formula will produce 40 primes for the consecutive
> ```
>
> values n = 0 to 39. However, when n =
>   40, 40^(2) + 40 + 41 = 40(40 + 1) + 41
>   is divisible by 41, and certainly when
>   n = 41, 41² + 41 + 41 is clearly
>   divisible by 41.
>
> ```
> Using computers, the incredible formula n² − 79n + 1601 was
> ```
>
> discovered, which produces 80 primes
>   for the consecutive values n = 0 to
>   79. The product of the coefficients, −79 and 1601, is −126479.
>
> ```
> Considering quadratics of the form:
>
> n² + an + b, where |a| < 1000 and |b| < 1000
>
> where |n| is the modulus/absolute value of n
> e.g. |11| = 11 and |−4| = 4
>
> Find the product of the coefficients, a and b, for the
> ```
>
> quadratic expression that produces the
>   maximum number of primes for
>   consecutive values of n, starting with
>   n = 0.

This is the problem for [Euler 27](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=27).

I have attempted a solution for trying to find the equation n^2 + n + 41 to see if my logic is correct then I will attempt to see if it works on the actual problem. Here is my code (I will place comments explaining the whole program also, I would start reading from the int main function first) just make sure to read the comments so you can understand my logic:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int c) {
    int test;
    //Eliminate with some simple primes to start off with to increase speed...
    if (c == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    if (c == 3) { 
        return true;
    }
    if (c == 5) { 
        return true;
    }
    //Actual elimination starts here.
    if (c <= 1 || c % 2 == 0 || c % 3 == 0 || c % 5 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    //Then using brute force test if c is divisible by anything lower than it except 1
    //only if it gets past the first round of elimination, and if it doesn't
    //pass this round return false.
    for (test = c; test > 1; test--) {
        if (c % test == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //If the c pasts all these tests it should be prime, therefore return true.
    return true;
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    //a as in n^2 + "a"n + b
    int a = 0;
    //b as in n^2 + an + "b"
    int b = 0;
    //n as in "n"^2 + a"n" + b
    int n = 0;
    //this will hold the result of n^2 + an + b so if n = 1 a = 1
    //and b = 1 then c = 1^2 + 1(1) + 1 = 3
    int c = 0;
    //bestChain: This is to keep track for the longest chain of primes 
    //in a row found.
    int bestChain = 0;
    //chain: the current amount of primes in a row.
    int chain = 0;
    //bestAB: Will hold the value for the two numbers a and b that
    // give the most consecutive primes.
    int bestAB[2] = { 0 };
    //Check every value of a in this loop
    for (a = 0; a < 40; a++) {
        //Check every value of b in this loop.
        for (b = 0; b < 42; b++) {
            //Give c a starting value
            c = n*n + a*n + b;
            //(1)Check if it is prime. And keep checking until it is not
            //and keep incrementing n and the chain. (2)If it not prime then che
            //ck if chain is the highest chain and assign the bestChain
            // to the current chain. (3)Either way reset the values
            // of n and chain.
            //(1)
            while (isPrime(c) == true) {
                n++;
                c = n*n + a*n + b;
                chain++;
            }
            //(2)
            if (bestChain < chain) {
                bestChain = chain;
                bestAB[0] = a;
                bestAB[1] = b;
                chain = 0;
                n = 0;
            }
            //(3)
            else {
                n = 0;
                chain = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //Lastly print out the best values of a and b.
    cout << bestAB[0] << " " << bestAB[1]; 
    return 0;
}
```

But, I get the results 0 and 2 for a and b respectively, why is this so? Where am I going wrong? If it is still unclear just ask for more clarification on a specific area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your isprime method is inefficient -- but also wrong:

```
for (test = c; test > 1; test--) {
    if (c % test == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

in the first iteration of the for loop, `test` = `c`, so `c % test` is just `c % c`, which will always be 0.  So your isprime method claims everything is non-prime (other than 2, 3, 5)

Comment: I feel stupid. Thanks! I will accept when I can.. It works so far. Update: I got the answer for the actual problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (test = c; test > 1; test--) {
    if (c % test == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Do you see the problem with that?  If not, try working out some small sample values by hand.

Comment: Once you see the problem with that, there is a simple way to speed up the loop significantly:  you only need to test the **odd** values of `test` that are `< sqrt(c)`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, your problem is in the isPrime method (`test = c`, so `test % c = c % c == 0` is always true).

You can make your `isPrime` function run in O(sqrt(n)) instead of O(n) by initializing `test` to sqrt(c) (and only checking odd numbers). It is easy to see that if a number A is divisible by B < sqrt(A), then C = A/B must be > sqrt(A). Thus if there are no divisors < sqrt(A), there will be no divisors > sqrt(A).

Of course, you can run it a whole lot faster even, by using a probabilistic primality test, e.g. [Miller-Rabin's primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).

Also, I'm not sure, but I suspect you might reach the limit of `int` fairly quickly. It's probably a better idea to use `unsigned long long` from the start, before you start getting strange errors due to overflow & wrapping.